# warning: constant Publisher::TimeoutError is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I am looking for help and I am totally STUCK.

In case you are wondering where the OCN comes from: https://github.com/StratusNetwork/OCN

```
ruby --version: 2.1.5
bundler --version: 1.6.1
```

Hello, I am trying to execute this command in `rails c`, but I get the following message:

```
buxar@buxar-VirtualBox:~/OCN2/OCN$ rails c
^[[A^[[ALoading development environment (Rails 4.2.4)
Ignoring eventmachine-1.0.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.0.4
irb(main):001:0> 
irb(main):002:0* Repository[:data].load_models
/home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/workers/publisher.rb:4: warning: constant Publisher::TimeoutError is deprecated
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /minecraft/repo/data/models
    from /home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/models/buildable/store.rb:17:in `chdir'
    from /home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/models/buildable/store.rb:17:in `glob'
    from /home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/models/buildable/transfer.rb:34:in `paths'
    from /home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/models/buildable/import.rb:99:in `load'
    from /home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/models/buildable.rb:99:in `block in load_models'
    from /home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/models/buildable.rb:98:in `each'
    from /home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/models/buildable.rb:98:in `load_models'
    from /home/buxar/OCN2/OCN/app/models/repository/data.rb:26:in `load_models'
    from (irb):2
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:37:in `require'
    from script/rails:37:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: Check the `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory /minecraft/repo/data/models ...` message

Comment: According to the instructions of the web:

The OCN-Data repo contains static configuration data for the database. This includes things like permission groups, server families, and game types. Clone it somewhere, and create a symlink to it from / minecraft / repo / data. From the Web repo, run rails to start a Rails shell session. From the Rails shell, run Repository [: data] .load_models to import everything from the Data repo into MongoDB.

But already create the symlink, also try to paste the files directly in minecraft / repo / data the folder "models" is there, but the error persists

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem in this year (2020) i have the solution.

***Steps:***

1. Go to OCN project web -> app -> models -> **repository.rb**
2. Replace  `BASE_PATH = '/minecraft/repo'` to  `BASE_PATH = 'your_directory_stored/minecraft/repo'`, in my case is in `BASE_PATH = '/home/minecraft/repo'`
3. Type `rails c` and paste `Repository[:data].load_models` thats return **`=> true`**

If doesn't work in rare cases create a symlink and then follow the steps above.